# Problema com Upload de arquivo no asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Upload de arquivos através do FileUpload tem um tamanho máximo de 4 MB, após pesquisar eu encontrei aqui no stackoverflow que deveria adicionar :

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

O problema é que o site executa se eu adicionar estas informações, mais tenho o mesmo erro, como eu poderia resolver este problema? agradeço

Answer (score 2):

O problema do site não executar era o fato de repetir o httpRuntime que e criado automaticamente dentro do system.web desta forma:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Para resolver eu comentei está linda e adicionei:

```
 <!---tamanho do arquivo-->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

Também adicionei:

```
 <!--tamanho do arquivo-->
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

Agora eu consigo fazer o upload de arquivo com tamanho maior